# How do I return the max value with query, when there's two columns?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a spreadsheet with a dashboard that tracks my finances. Right now, I'm trying to come up with a dynamic way to find the day I have the highest incoming transaction occurring.

I'm trying to use the query function to do that, but the table is returning empty.

This is the formula I'm using:

```
=QUERY(Income_Data_wDate,"SELECT * where I= '"&Max(Income_Data_wDate)&"'")
```

I used named ranges to reference the database. I tried using the actual range but it does the same thing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following method to return the max value, I think your original code also not working in SQL method?

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"Select * Order By B Desc Limit 1")
```

[image]